# Struggling with role.setMentionable(true)

Tags: discord.js

I have a problem since yesterday.
I try to do role.setMentionable(true), but it doesn't change, no error. I have the same code on another server with all identical role perms, but it works on it.
Back to my first bot, I tried to change a superior and Admin role, no error. I did console.log(role), it returns well the role.
Please help I tried everything :(

```
var role_id = "id";
var role = client.guilds.get(serv_id).roles.get(role_id);
role.setMentionable(true)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please insert your [code](/help/reprex) to your question. Without it, it's hard to help... Also, read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @FZs I added, but I don't think that'll help

Comment: You must now that this method is a promose so maybe await this codeline and it'll work

Comment: Thank you so much @GillesHeinesch! Finally worked, I don't know why, but my other bot's code works without that, but thanks a lot!

Comment: It‘s because of the promise :) @Nitoxym